# How to design a header in magento 2.3 with Logo, Navbar and cart in one line?

Tags: header, navigation, themes, frontend, magento2

I want to design a header by extending the Luma theme. I have attached pic on how I want the header design. Can someone please help me with this? Am new to Magento and still learning things. I am using Magento 2.3.2 and have created a custom theme in app/design/frontend/Vendor_name/theme_name/ by extending Luma theme as parent theme. THANKS.

Please refer this link for reference header image, I want same header as in image below,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZtr8.png

Comment: Please include code or description of what you have already tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have achived the same design with the below steps.
Note am extending blank theme.

1. In your theme open the file Magento_theme/layout/default.xml.
2. Move the navigation after the logo
3. Create a new container to group all the three right side icons
4. Move the new container "header.actions" after navigation
5. Move the minicart, search and user icon into the header.actions container
6. Clear the cache and refresh the browser

```html
<move element="catalog.topnav" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo"/>
<container name="header.actions" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header-actions"/> 
<move element="header.actions" destination="header-wrapper" after="catalog.topnav"/>
<move element="top.search" destination="header.actions" after="-" />
<move element="minicart" destination="header.actions"  before="-"/>
<move element="my-account-link" destination="header.actions" after="minicart"/>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Can I know how to do this by extending luma theme? I get some misalignments if I do in luma. And How can I assign the "user" icon for "my account link" ? And How can I change the default the search bar to icon type as shown above? Sorry for so many questions as am new to magento learning. THANKS.

Comment: But I am getting misalignments by extending in both luma and blank. The my account, search and cart comes below the nav bar.

Comment: I believe the same xml instructions should work well even if you are extending luma. Just check whether all the elements are in desired location using inspect element(within .header.content). If everything is ok then you should style with less to fix the alignment issues. For the icon you have to work with less(css) files.

Comment: Hi How did you manage to fix the responsive menu?@DavidFrancisRaj